# How to pass array into the doctrine query findBy?

Tags: php

Before I had filter params like below:

```
width: 195
diameter: 15
load: 91
```

So, I simply use following query to retrieve result.

```
$list = $this->entityManager->getRepository(List::class)->findBy($filterArray);
```

Now, my requirement is changed. I can pass comma-separated string

```
width: 195,245
diameter: 15
load: 91
```

So, first I convert this string into array:

```
[
  "width" => [
    0 => "195"
    1 => "245"
  ]
  "diameter" => [
    0 => "15"
  ]
  "load" => [
    0 => "91"
  ]
]
```

Now I am not sure how to make a query. Filter param can vary. Its not necessary that all the param are passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `findBy` function you can filter with an array param. For example, if you need to find entities with `width: 195,245` you can pass the data like this

```
['width' => [195, 245]]
```

For removing the empty params you can use `array_filter` function

```
$list = $this->entityManager->getRepository(List::class)->findBy(array_filter($filterArray));
```

Later if your params will grow, you can use the Doctrine QB for filtering your data

Comment: @lhor Kostrov, I do not need to provide key `width`. Just pass array_filter($filterArray) will do the job ?

Comment: no, you need to pass your array with the params like this [ "width" => [ 0 => "195" 1 => "245" ] "diameter" => [ 0 => "15" ] "load" => [ 0 => "91" ] ] and call array_filter on this params, for removing empty values

Comment: @lhor Kostrov I have no access to check if right now. but looks like that should work. Thanks.